# How to show extentReports log details in console

Tags: log4j, selenium-extent-report

I am using extent Reports for capturing logs in my selenium test. I am able to log all the information in the test report. I also need to show this logs in run time on console(windows machine). Can anyone help em to do that

Comment: What have you tried for Log4j ? Please share your code,

Comment: I am not using log4j. i am using extent report for the generating logs in the test report. i want to show these logs in the console as log4j does.